DatePickerDialog. Смена background'a у выбранного дня
Использую стандартный андроидовский пикер. И сейчас он выглядит вот так.

Есть ли какая-либо возможность изменить background у выбранного дня, чтобы это выглядело, например, вот так?

Изменение цвета у выбранного дня не вызывает проблем. Для этого есть соответствующая переменная в style. Нов вот с background - засада.
Стиль меняю так:
<style name="MyPickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>

и потом устанавливаю его в конструкторе диалога:
val dialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), R.style.MyPickerDialog, this, year, month, day)


Добавьте пример стиля как вы цвет дня меняете, а background не меняется.

добавил. после этого цвет меняется у выбранного дня, но мне нужно изменить именно drawable туда передать.

Не похоже что DatePicker использует drawable background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46579413/5479247
